# Can I set the cycle that DataReceived event occurs from SerialPort?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a program that reads and writes a hexadecimal byte[] from `SerialPort`.

My program only use 5 bytes(five hexadecimal) in one communication.

The problem is that the DataReceived occurence cycle is random. So, sometimes it reads 5 bytes, sometimes it reads 4 bits.

[image]

I always want DataReceived to read 5 bytes. Is it possible?

Below code is the logic of program that I wrote.

```cs
serialPort.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);
```

```cs
serialPort.DataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    var receiveSize = serialPort.BytesToRead;
    var buffer = new byte[receiveSize];

    serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    this.Invoke(() =>
    {
        readRichTextBox.AppendText($"{string.Join(" ", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer))}\n");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after creating a empty `List<byte>`. Is there a better way?

```cs
private List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
```

```cs
serialPort.DataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    var receiveSize = serialPort.BytesToRead;
    var buffer = new byte[receiveSize];

    serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    this.Invoke(() =>
    {
        foreach (var b in buffer)
        {
            bytes.Add(b);
        }

        if (bytes.Count == 10)
        {
            readRichTextBox.AppendText($"{string.Join(" ", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes.ToArray()))}\n");
            bytes.Clear();
        }
    });
};
```